# Ruby Mac OS X 10.9.2

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out this error.

I'm on mac os x 10.9.2 and my ruby -v says ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

The error I get is:

```
chadd:homebrew-openmw-master chadd$ ruby test.rb 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- formula (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

The code I'm trying to run looks like this, but its left incomplete because you don't really need the rest:

```
require 'formula'

class OpenmwBoost < Formula
  homepage 'http://www.boost.org'
  url 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0.tar.gz/download'
```

Why does my version of ruby not find 'formula', not its a native package that should come with ruby.

Comment: Formula doesn't come with Ruby. I'm not sure how to get because I haven't made a homebrew package but it doesn't come with Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the [forumla gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/formula), with `gem install formula`.